# Replacing entire string when a single word is in the string R

Tags: r, string

I was wondering if anyone had come across a solution to this problem when cleaning up data in R.
The idea is to have a list of strings for example:

```
strings = c("hello world", "goodbye all", "help is appreciated", "hello sam")
```

then we would go through the list of strings and whenever a certain word is found the entire string would be replaced.

Therefore if we are looking for the word "hello" it would be replaced with "math"

so the output I would be looking for would be:

```
"math", "goodbye all", "help is appreciated", "math".
```

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `grepl`:

```
strings = c("hello world", "goodbye all", "help is appreciated", "hello sam")
> strings[grepl("hello",strings)] <- "math"
> strings
[1] "math"                "goodbye all"         "help is appreciated" "math"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sub(".*hello.*", "math", strings)
```

giving:

```
[1] "math"                "goodbye all"         "help is appreciated"
[4] "math"
```